# MS Excel has stopped working during a query (by using vba) in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

After connecting to MySQL and perform a database query (via VBA), Excel crashes when I try to assign a variable to the elements of the resultset.

It worked fine at the beginning, but then suddenly it stopped to work.
Excel 2016. MySql 5.1.35 Community Server (GPL)

```vb
    Sub doSomething()

        call conectBD
        Dim cSQL as String
        Dim rstSet as RecordSet
        Dim myName as String

        cSQL = "SELECT name FROM tbNames WHERE id_name=3"
        Set rstSet = New ADOBD.Recordset

        rstSet.Open cSQL, conexao, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        myName = rstSet!name 'Excel crashes here'

        rstSet.Close
        Set rstSet = Nothing 

        call disconectBD
    end Sub

    'Connect to BD' 
    sub conectBD()
        Set conexao = New ADODB.Connection'Connection'
              conexao.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" _
                                & "SERVER=localhost;" _
                                & "DATABASE=DB;" _
                                & "UID=user;" _
                                & "PASSWORD=password"       
              conexao.Open 
    End sub

    'Disconnet to BD'
    sub disconectBD()
        conexao.close 
        set conexao = nothing
    end sub
```

I expect it works just like it did at the beginning.

Comment: Does an error message appear (if so, what is the error message and the error number) or does Excel just stop working completely?